# The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache

Tags: php, apache

I'm install apache server and php on Windows 7 and configured its.
But when i'm trying to load php_test.php page(localhost/php_test.php) i get an error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /php_test.php was not found on this server.

In httpd.conf i've written next:

```
ServerName localhost

DocumentRoot "D:/project/"

<Directory "D:/project/">
   Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

What is the problem? I can provide any information from httpd.conf and php.ini if this is need.

Comment: I see that you have "AllowOverride All" declared. Do you have a .htaccess file by any chance in your document root?

Comment: Probably a stupid question but have you got PHP added as an application type to your httpd.conf?  
As in:  
    LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    PHPIniDir "C:/php"

Comment: Yes, Andris. It's exist.

Comment: does D:/project/php_test.php exist you could also check the apache logs in linux they are located in /var/log on windows im not so sure

Comment: Of course, encodes, file exist. My OS is Windows, i will check log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. When I've installing appache I've written wrong server name. I was confused that in httpd.conf server name was right (localhost) but still wasn't worked.

UPD (for commentators)

I fix it by reinstall apache server. My mistake was because of i enter wrong server name during installation (seems first time i wrote ip adress). I don't remember what step was it. I reinstall server, wrote "localhost" as server name and it works.

Comment: Can you please specify where have you written down the wrong ServerName? And what are the steps to fix?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can you please elaborate how you solved your issue. Thanks